# Typescript type guards don't work when extracting to a function

Tags: typescript

When I'm using the native code directly, typescript knows the correct type inside the block, for example:

```
function test(value: string | string[]) {

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        // ts knows that value is array
        return value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

But when I am trying to abstract the logic to a function it does not work anymore.

```
function isArray(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value);
}

function test(value: string | string[]) {

    if (isArray(value)) {
        return value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

There is a way to do this without explicitly write the `as` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeguards have a special return type. You need to add it to your function as well.

```js
function isArray(value): value is Array<any> {
    return Array.isArray(value);
}
```

Comment: isArray does have that type defined but for some reason it doesn't carry over to your function. without the return type it returns boolean (which is true but not the truth)